# Why does the compgen command work in the Linux terminal but not with process::Command?

Tags: shell, terminal, rust

The command `compgen` works fine in the Linux Terminal, but causes a panic when using Command::new.

My code:

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let status = Command::new("compgen")
        .status()
        .expect("failed to execute process");
    println!("process exited with: {}", status);
}
```

The error message:

```
    Compiling terminal v0.1.0 (file:///home/user/programmates/RUST/Terminal/terminal)
     Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.66 secs
     Running `target/debug/terminal`
thread 'main' panicked at 'failed to execute process: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', libcore/result.rs:945:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

Comment: It's a shell builtin not an executable so you need to invoke the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all commands available to the shell are runnable with `process::Command`; [`compgen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) is a bash [builtin command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192373/what-are-shell-built-in-commands-in-linux) and doesn't work outside of it, because it is not a standalone program - it is embedded within the shell.

It is, however, possible to invoke bash and execute `compgen` by passing the following [option](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash) to it:

```
Command::new("bash").args(&["-c", "compgen"])
```