# rbenv- is it risky to rely on builtin shell commands such as "set", since builtins could be implemented differently by different shells?

Tags: shell, rbenv

I use zsh as my shell, and rbenv to manage my Ruby versions.  I am diving into rbenv's internals to learn how it works.  I type

```
vim `which bundle`
```

into my terminal and I see the following code:

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/env bash
  2 set -e
...
```

After the shebang, the first line of code is `set -e`.  Wanting to learn more about `set`, I type `man set` into my terminal, but I get:

```
BUILTIN(1)                                                   General Commands Manual
```

in response.  From this I determine that `set` is a builtin command.  From [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24706709/2143275), I interpret that to mean that builtins such as `set` could be implemented differently depending on which terminal the user is employing (i.e. bash vs zsh vs fish).  To quote the answer:

> Every Unix shell has at least some builtin commands. These builtin commands are part of the shell, and are implemented as part of the shell's source code... **Different shells have different builtins, though there will be a whole lot of overlap in the basic set.**

I'm assuming that the `set` command is part of this "basic set" that the answer refers to, right?  That would make the most sense to me, since the authors of `rbenv` are quite experienced and I would think they're unlikely to rely on a command which could behave differently depending on the user's shell.

My question is two-fold:

1. If my above assumption is correct, where is that "basic set" of commands defined?  Is it some sort of officially-recognized, industry-wide standard that all shells must adhere to?  And if so, what is that industry-wide standard known as, so I can Google it and learn more?
2. If my assumption is wrong, and if the `set` terminal command is *not* part of some broad standard, does that mean that different shells could implement `set` in different ways, possibly producing different behavior?  And wouldn't it therefore be dangerous for a widely-used program like `rbenv` to rely on such a command, since it could behave differently on different users' machines?

Comment: As long as you stick to features from POSIX sh, you're usually pretty safe.

Comment: @Shawn OK, so I take it that POSIX is the name of the industry-wide standard that I mention in question #1 above, correct?  And I see from [this link](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) that `set` is one of the "special built-in commands" mentioned in the POSIX standard.  So I'm assuming this is the reason why it's safe to rely on `set` in the manner I describe in my question.  Let me know if I'm mistaken with any of these assumptions.